# Tensorflow Object detection api - prediction with multiple boundary boxes problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection-api

I'm trying to predict seven facial expressions using faster-rcnn with TensorFlow objection API. I have trained the model on 1,00,000 steps on the fer2013 dataset after training when I predict an image using the trained model I get results like as shown in the image =>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSbV.png) can anyone help me out why it is that way?

```py
    # Import packages
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
IMAGE_NAME = 'test1.jpg'

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

# Path to image
PATH_TO_IMAGE = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,IMAGE_NAME)

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 7

# Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `king`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Load image using OpenCV and
# expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
# i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
image = cv2.imread('/content/2.jpg')
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=10,
    min_score_thresh=0.60)

# # All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
# cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)

# # Press any key to close the image
# cv2.waitKey(0)

# # Clean up
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()

%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2



# The underlying representation is a numpy array!
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 20), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Can you post some code so that we can understand your problem better?

Comment: I have edit the code kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Non-maximum suppression to remove those extra bounding boxes.
Check this repo https://github.com/ajaichemmanam/Emovere-ML

Comment: but im using faster rcnn this repo is based on cnn

Comment: Faster RCNN proposes regions for classification. The model may propose multiple regions with varying sizes/aspect ratio for the same object with different confidence scores. Hence we use Non-maxmum suppression to remove overlapping bounding boxes.

Comment: For instance, an NMS implementation is provided here - https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/utils/nms.py

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a

Comment: this article says that it is applied automatically in faster rcnn